# Angular.js unable to change scope variable value just after a different function call

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-ng-click

I'm trying to implement a Refresh button for fetching latest search results from an external index. When I click on the Refresh button the icon is supposed to spin. My plan was to have a scope variable for deciding if the icon should spin or not. For that I'm using a variable called `$scope.refreshing`

**My view**

```html
<button class="refresh-button" ng-click="refresh()">
    <i class="fa fa-refresh ng-scope" ng-class="{'fa-spin': refreshing.state}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         Refresh
</button>
```

**My controller**

```
      $scope.refreshing ={state: false};
      $scope.refresh = function(){
        $scope.refreshing.state = true;
        $scope.search();
        $scope.refreshing.state = false;
      }
```

The `$scope.search()` sends an HTTP request to a server and displays the new results. But I'm having the problem such that the `$scope.refreshing` variable change doesn't happen sequentially such that it becomes false only after calling the search function due to the asynchronous nature. Because of that the icon doesn't spin.

**Actual**
[image]
**Expected**
[image]

Would it be possible to perform this without doing any changes to the `search()` function.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because angular isn't refreshing the digest quickly enough. You can give it a 'nudge' with [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) (and there are other methods as well). Something like

```
  $scope.refreshing ={state: false};
  $scope.refresh = function(){
    $scope.refreshing.state = true;
    $timeout( function() {
       $scope.search();
       $scope.refreshing.state = false;
    }, 100)
  }
```

Of course, you'll need to include `$timeout` as a dependency in your controller/directive whatever.